# R maximum with NAs in a vector

Tags: r, max

I have a problem. Lines where PROJECT="SNOP" are missing (they don't appear in df6) while they were present in df5. PROJECT = "SNOP" lines contain only NAs for the VERSION2 variable. Someone can help me? Here is my code:

```
which(df5$PROJECT=="SNOP") #200 lines appear

df6 <- df5 %>% 
  group_by(PROJECT) %>% 
  filter(VERSION2 == ifelse(!all(is.na(VERSION2)), max(VERSION2, na.rm=T), NA)) %>%
  ungroup()

which(df6$PROJECT=="SNOP") #missing lines PROJECT="Snop" #answer: integer(0)
```

Comment: can you provide some of your data with `dput(df5)` or `dput(head(df5))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is probably because "SNOP" has all `NA` values and `filter` drops them.

Consider this small example.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(a = rep(c(1:2), each  =3), b = c(1:3, NA, NA, NA))
```

Using your code, we do :

```
df %>%
   group_by(a) %>%
   filter(b == ifelse(!all(is.na(b)), max(b, na.rm=TRUE), NA))

#      a     b
#  <int> <int>
#1     1     3
```

Notice how `a = 2` is dropped.

Now you can decide what you want to do to those groups where all values are `NA`. For example, the below keeps all the rows where there are `NA`'s.

```
df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  filter(if(!all(is.na(b))) b == max(b, na.rm=T) else TRUE)

#      a     b
#  <int> <int>
#1     1     3
#2     2    NA
#3     2    NA
#4     2    NA
```